# npm express-session cannot get value or is empty

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am using express-session to save some values from my router and to display them later. However even if I console.log the req.session.euro_amount right after I set it, it shows the correct amount.

routes/api/convert.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const CC = require('currency-converter-lt')
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let amount_e = parseInt(req.body.amount_e);
    let amount_k = parseInt(req.body.amount_k
    let currencyConverter = new CC()

    if(!amount_e){
        // Convert to Euro
        currencyConverter.from("HRK").to("EUR").amount(amount_k).convert().then((response) => {
            console.log(response); // Correct value that I want to save
            req.session.euro_amount = response;
            console.log("Set amount in session: " + req.session.euro_amount); // Output: Set amount in session: 0.65
        })
    }
    res.redirect('/');
```

routes/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let euro_amount = req.session.euro_amount;
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', euro_amount });
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js (simplified):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var session = require('express-session');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var convertRouter = require('./routes/api/convert');

var app = express(); 

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');  

app.use(session({secret: 'S0meFancyS3c3t', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, secure: false}));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/convert', convertRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

The index.js router is working because if I overwrite the amount_euro manually it gets transported to the frontend without issues.

Is there a wrong way on how I initiate the session in the app.js or some other setting that I am missing with this setup?

The concrete problem is that I cannot access `req.session.euro_amount` inside the `routes/index.js` file.

Comment: Hi, I did not get the issue. What are the current and the expected behavior?

Comment: @ypahalajani just updated the question with the exact problem. I cannot access req.session.euro_amount - it is always empty. Somehow it seems that the value gets lost or not save in the session between api/convert.js and routes/index.js

Comment: The code looks alright to me. Can you define the flow as well? Like I am assuming on '/' route you have some form through which you call the '/api/convert' route which saves a new `euro_amount'  in the session so that the next time user hits '/', the euro_amount is prepopulated from the session. Are you doing the same or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In your router. post,  u may need to import body-parser, that is require ('body-parser')  for the back end to get the data u posted from the front end with req.body.

Without the body-parser, the req.body would not be able to get the data you posted.